# Find correspondig key of a specific value in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary which vlaues are list type and they are unique for each key. 
`d = {'key1': [1,2,3], 'key2': [4,5,6], 'key3': [7,8,9]}` 
And I have a variable called `a = 3`. Now I want to find the key corresponding to this variable.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Try to solve it by yourself first, it is  not that difficult. The most straightforward way would be to cycle through `d` and return the key if the value for the key includes `a`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
required_key = None
for key,value in d.items():
    if a in value:
        required_key = key
        break
print(required_key)
```